# React Native Release app error in play console

Tags: google-play, react-native

I sent my application to the play store and in the play console appeared some clusters of error, after some downlaods. In my cellphone, this kind of failure has never happened.

Play Console Error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3334) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17 (Unknown Source) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1725) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6694) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:769)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass (BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:312)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver (ActivityThread.java:3329)
```

My Setting Gradle:

```
    rootProject.name = project_name
    include ':react-native-firebase'
    project(':react-native-firebase').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/android')
    include ':react-native-snackbar'
    project(':react-native-snackbar').projectDir = new         File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-snackbar/android')
    include ':react-native-vector-icons'
    project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
    include ':react-native-text-input-mask'
    project(':react-native-text-input-mask').projectDir = new     File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-text-input-    mask/android')

    include ':app'

My build.gradle

    buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
    }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            maven {
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
            }
            maven {
                url 'https://maven.google.com/'
                name 'Google'
            }
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }

ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "26.0.3"
    minSdkVersion = 16
    compileSdkVersion = 26
    targetSdkVersion = 26
    supportLibVersion = "26.1.0"
}
```

My app/build.gradle

```
...
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    compile project(':react-native-snackbar')
    implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-text-input-mask')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:15.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar' 

}
```

I do not know what's going on and how to fix it. Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a dex issue. You need to enable multidex support.

As you are targeting a minSDKVersion of 16 you need to add the following to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
```

You will also need to enable multidex in your `defaultConfig` in your `android/app/build.gradle`

```
defaultConfig {
  // there will be other things here like applicationId, minSdkVersion, versionCode etc.
  multiDexEnabled true
}
```

You also need to change the following line in your `MainApplication.java` from

`public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {`

to

`public class MainApplication extends MultiDexApplication implements ReactApplication {`

You can read more about enabling multidex here https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex as there are different ways to enable it depending on whether you override the `Application` class.

Comment: I tried to do this and it did not work. The same error has occurred again.